# Google Map not displaying on HTML <div>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-maps

I am trying to develop a web page where there are two containers. mainmapdiv covers the entire page while mainhomediv is placed on top of mainmapdiv. My objective is to hide mainhomediv and display a Google Map on the mainmapdiv on clicking an image (id=mapbutton). The code is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var map;
function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
    zoom: 8,    
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mainmapdiv"),mapOptions);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>

<script>
var map;
$(document).ready(function(){

//Click on button to display map
$('#mapbutton').click(function(){
    $('#mainhomediv').fadeTo("slow",0);
    $('#mainhomediv').css({opacity: 0});
    initialize();
});

//Click on Home to get back home div
$('#home').click(function(){
    $('#mainhomediv').fadeTo("slow",1);
    $('#mainhomediv').css({opacity: 1});
});
});
```

HTML CODE

```
<body>
<!--This is the primary container-->
<div id='#mainmapdiv' class='mainmapdiv'>
    <div id='#mainhomediv' class='mainhomediv'>
    .
    //Somewhere in here there is an image with id='mapbutton'
    .
    .
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Now when I click the image, mainhomediv gets hidden perfectly, but the map is not displayed on mainmapdiv.

I have imported the following scripts:

```
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/apijs?sensor=false"></script>
```

Comment: Does #mainhomediv have a height? Last time map didn't work for me when the containing div didn't have a height

Comment: I think you meant #mainmapdiv, as that is the container that will hold the map. And yes, I have set the height and width as 100% for it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know if this will solve, but you have to correct it :

Your JS link is wrong :http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/apijs?sensor=false

And you have # in your div's ID :

```
<div id='#mainmapdiv' class='mainmapdiv'>
<div id='#mainhomediv' class='mainhomediv'>
```

You have multiple `var map;` in your script.

Comment: The # in the id solved it! Why did I have # for the ids? God only knows!

Comment: This is what happened when we focus on something more difficult. We have in mind that jQuery use #id, so we put #id everywhere ! Glad That solve your problem ^_^

Answer (score 0):

You need to set Height and Width for `#mainhomediv`

eg:

```
#mainhomediv {
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
}
```